# Tableview rendering glitch

Tags: ios

I am trying to put a shadow around a thumbnail image on at tableview cell. However, when I do it, it doesn't render correctly as the screenshot below shows:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/27/iossimulatorscreenshot7r.png/

(sorry cant embed screenshots as a new user!)

On another tableview in the app, the same code works perfectly as shown:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/4/iossimulatorscreenshot7.png/

The code I am using is exactly the same for both:

```
ImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:image];
ImageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
ImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
```

The problem occurs when I try to put a shadow on the tableview too:

imageshack.us/content_round.php?page=done&l=img577/1947/iossimulatorscreenshot7.png

Any ideas?

I set up mostly everything using Storyboards, so maybe its somethings to do with that?

Comment: First image looking like you've bordered the `UITableViewCell` object and not the `UIImageView` object inside the cell. Try double checking your variables, IBOutlets and even just try putting a breakpoint to look at the objects true type in the debugger.

Comment: I just checked the debugger, the UIImageView is listed as a UITableViewCell object instead of a UIImageView...but on another tableview I have they are listed correctly and the code is the same. That still doesn't explain the shadow not rendering properly though...or does it? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(from my original comment) First image looking like you've bordered the `UITableViewCell` object and not the `UIImageView` object inside the cell.

It does explain it.

Your `UIImageView` is not actually your image view, it's a reference to the whole `UITableViewCell` which is why the border draws around the whole cell, not just the image. Since the border methods you call work on all `UIView` and both `UITableViewCell` and `UIImageView` happen to be sub-classes of `UIView` your app doesn't crash.

The question is... why are they wrong. How are you assigning your `ImageView` variable? Is it done in code or an IBOutlet? If it's an IBOutlet, check the "Connections Inspector" on your view controller and make sure you didn't accidentally hook the cell up instead of the image (this is my guess). If you did it in code, we'll probably need to see the code.

**Side note:** Convention says variable names should start with lowercase letters. Class names should start with uppercase letters. So `UIImageView *imageView;`

Comment: Okay, so I've fixed the border problem, turns out they were listed as `UITableViewCell` because 2 things had the same tag so were getting mixed up. But the shadow is still not fixed, [screenshot,](http://imageshack.us/content_round.php?page=done&l=img577/1947/iossimulatorscreenshot7.png) which is created using the code ``cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 0);
    cell.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    cell.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = .25;``

Comment: Try setting the shadow on the `cell.contentView` instead of the `cell` itself. I have a feelings that's what you are looking for. You might also want to take the shadow off the bottom cell so it doesn't stick out below the table.